# Understanding shapes in keras layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am learning Tensorflow and Keras to implement `LSTM` `many-to-many` model where the length of input sequence is equal to the length of the output sequence.

Sample Code:

Inputs:

```
voc_size = 10000
embed_dim = 64
lstm_units = 75
size_batch = 30
count_classes = 5
```

Model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ( Bidirectional, LSTM, 
                                Dense, Embedding, TimeDistributed )
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

def sample_build(embed_dim, voc_size, batch_size, lstm_units, count_classes):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=voc_size, 
                     output_dim=embed_dim,input_length=50))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_units,return_sequences=True),
                                         merge_mode="ave"))
    model.add(Dense(200))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(count_classes+1)))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                      optimizer='rmsprop', 
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model 


sample_model = sample_build(embed_dim,voc_size, 
                                    size_batch, rnn_units,
                                    count_classes)
```

I am having trouble understanding the shapes of input and output for each layer. For example, the shape of the output of `Embedding_Layer` is `(BATCH_SIZE, time_steps, length_of_input)` and in this case, it is `(30, 50, 64)`.

Similarly, the output shape of `Bidirectional LSTM` later is `(30, 50, 75)`. This is will be the input for the next `Dense Layer` with `200` units. But the shape of the weight matrix of `Dense Layer` is (number of `units` in the current layer, number of units in the previous layer, which is `(200,75)` in this case. So how does the matrix calculation happen between `2D` shape of the `Dense Layer` and the `3D` shape of the Bidirectional Layer? Any explanations on the shape clarification will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The Dense can do 3D operation, it will flatten the the input to shape (batch_size * time_steps, features) and then apply a dense layer and reshape it back to orignal (batch_size, time_steps, units). In keras's [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) of Dense layer, it says:

> Note: If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the last axis of the inputs and axis 1 of the kernel (using tf.tensordot). For example, if input has dimensions (batch_size, d0, d1), then we create a kernel with shape (d1, units), and the kernel operates along axis 2 of the input, on every sub-tensor of shape (1, 1, d1) (there are batch_size * d0 such sub-tensors). The output in this case will have shape (batch_size, d0, units).

Another point regarding the output of `Embedding` layer. As you said, it is correct that it is a 3D output, but correctly the shape correspond to (BATCH_SIZE, input_dim, embeddings_dim)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in this case, through flattening with the input for the ```Dense Layer``` be ```(30*50, 75) => (1500,75)```. In that case if the shape of the ```weight_matrix``` of the ```Dense Layer``` is ```(200,75)``` I don't understand how the calculation happens and the reshaping. Can you please explain that?